# android поменять цвет текста в statusbarcolor

Tags: android, activity, actionbar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять цвет текста в colorPrimaryDark
получается мне нужно чтобы colorPrimaryDark был белым, а текст соответсвенно черным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел выход из данной ситуации, мне помогло, читайте и ознакамливайтесь
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color

Answer (score 1):

Текст в `statusbar`'e меняется автоматически, взависимости от версии `API` Android и цвета, который вы используете в `colorPrimaryDark`. Самостоятельно поменять цвет текста или иконок нельзя. Такой возможности просто не существует.

Comment: когда у меня белый statusbar, текст времени  и т.д. тоже белый, и что нет способа сделать его черным?

Comment: @FCAndroidFC, таким бывает страдают не гугловские прошивки. Встречал такое на miui.